# State-space model (SSM) for SDE

Tags: calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Given an SDE:
$$
d\mathrm{\boldsymbol{X}}_t = \mu(\mathrm{\boldsymbol{X}}_t)dt + \sigma(\mathrm{\boldsymbol{X}}_t)d\mathrm{\boldsymbol{B}}_t
$$

Under which conditions we can model this SDE by a State-Space Model (SSM)?

$$
\mathrm{\boldsymbol{X}}_{t+1} = F(\mathrm{\boldsymbol{X}}_t) + \mathrm{\boldsymbol{\omega}}_{t}
$$

Additionally, if $\mathrm{\boldsymbol{\omega}}_{t}$ is zero-mean, could I use a deterministic Runge-Kutta method to predict the mean of $\mathrm{\boldsymbol{X}}_{t+1}$:

$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathrm{\boldsymbol{X}}_{t+1}] = RK(\mathrm{\boldsymbol{X}}_{t})
$$

Thank you very much!